# Having 2 Recyclerview in one layout. The vertical recyclerview with checkbox is either not checking or checking other position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerview in one layout. The vertical recyclerview shows all the user and the horizontal recyclerview shows the selected user from vertical recyclerview. The vertical recyclerview has a checkbox(clickable=false) to know that the user picks it and to do that I created an interface for vertical recyclerview, an ItemCheck and for the horizontal I created an interface of onItemClick. So my plan is when user click in vertical recyclerview it will add the item on the horizontal view and when the user unCheck it, the item will be remove to the horizontal recyclerview. And in the horizontal recyclerview, when the user clicks the item, the item will be remove in the selected user and in the vertical recyclerview it will uncheck the checkbox. This is the code for doing that.

**EDIT:**

***In the Activity:***

```
private void setUpAdapter() {
    mUsersAdapter = new PickMemberAdapter(PickMemberActivity.this, mUserNameList,
            mUserDescList, mUserPicList, new PickMemberAdapter.RecyclerViewItemClick() {

        @Override
        public void OnItemCheckClickListener(PickMemberAdapter.UsersViewHolders holder,
                                             String name, int position) {

            String userKey = mUserKey.get(position);

            if (!holder.mCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                mSelectedUser.add(userKey);
                mSelectedName.add(name);

            } else {
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                mSelectedUser.remove(userKey);
                mSelectedName.remove(name);
            }

            mUsersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSelectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(PickMemberActivity.this, mSelectedUser.toString()
                    + "\n" + mSelectedName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    mSelectedAdapter = new SelectedUserAdapter(mSelectedName,
            new SelectedUserAdapter.RecyclerViewUnselect() {

                @Override
                public void ItemRemoveClick(String name, int position) {
                    String userKey = mUserKey.get(position);

                    mSelectedUser.remove(userKey);
                    mSelectedName.remove(name);

                    mUsersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mSelectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(PickMemberActivity.this, mSelectedUser.toString()
                            + "\n" + mSelectedName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

    mSearchList.setAdapter(mUsersAdapter);
    mSelectedUserList.setAdapter(mSelectedAdapter);
}
```

***In the Adapter***

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UsersViewHolders holder, int position) {

    holder.setName(mUserNameList.get(position));
    holder.setDesc(mUserDescList.get(position));
    holder.setImage(mUserPicList.get(position));

    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.OnItemCheckClickListener(holder,
                    mUserNameList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()), holder.getAdapterPosition());

        }

    });
}
    public interface RecyclerViewItemClick {

    void OnItemCheckClickListener(UsersViewHolders holder, String name, int position);

}
```

Now my problem is the checkbox is either not checking or checking another position.

[image]

It should look like this (from Messenger Lite app)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating data of RecyclerView so you should notify adapter. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you update list.

```
    mSearchList.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mSelectedUserList.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I solved this problem to maintain separate boolean for check and uncheck in user model and user it onBindViewHolder to update view.

Comment: Yep I added it. I'll update my code but there's another problem. The checkbox is either not checking or checking to another position

Comment: I solved this problem to maintain separate boolean for check and uncheck in user model and user it onBindViewHolder to update view.

Comment: what about if you have searchview? How can I save the check state of the checkbox?